# Relation between a set and its interior

Tags: general-topology

Let $C[0,1]$ be a space of continuous functions $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with metric $d(f,g)=\sup |f(x)-g(x)|$. Find the interior of

$$A= \{ f \in C[0,1] : \exists t\in [0,\frac{1}{2} ] \ f(t)=0 \}$$

$$B= \{ f \in C[0,1] : \exists t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}) \ f(t)=0 \}$$

My solution:
$\operatorname{Int}(B)=B$, because for every function $f \in \operatorname{Int}(B)$ I can can set $r$ so small that the distance between that functions and functions in $B(f,r)$ have to fulfill the condition $\exists t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}) \ f(t)=0$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathrm{Int}(A)=\{f\in C[0,1]\mid\exists (x,y)\in[0,1/2]^2,f(x)f(y)\lt0\}=\mathrm{Int}(B)\quad(\ne\varnothing)$$

Comment: But $Int(B)$ I found is correct, aye?

Comment: Do you really think that Int(B) in my post coincides with B?

Comment: It does not, but I don't really see why your solution is correct - lets say I have a linear, nonnegative function that reaches 0 at 1=$\frac{1}{4}$ at stays at $0$ till $\frac{1}{2}$. Why does the function that are within a ball in this metric pass $y=0$? Wouldn't $\le$ be enough?

Comment: This is actually a good example: consider $f$ positive on $[0,1/4)$ and zero on $[1/4,1]$. Then, for every positive $\varepsilon$, $f+\varepsilon\gt0$ everywhere hence $f+\varepsilon$ is not in $B$. Since $f+\varepsilon$ is as close to $f$ as one wants, $f$ is in $B$ but not in $\mathrm{Int}(B)$.

Comment: I think I get where your confusion might come from: you seem to be thinking that the condition for some $f$ to be in $\mathrm{Int}(B)$ is that there exists functions in $B$ as close to $f$ as one wants. Well, this defines the *closure* of $B$, not its interior. For the interior, one asks that a whole ball centered at $f$ with positive radius be included in $B$.